# Auto detect already open browser instead of opening default one

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, browser, user-experience

I have multiple browsers on my system (Firefox, Google Chrome, and Chromium).
I normally use one of them at a time based on my needs,
but when other applications want to open a browser they always open their/system default browser.

Is there an application or script that is able to detect if a browser is already running and use it as current default browser?

**EDIT**

I don't want a browser to detect its own instance! I want a browser requester program/script to detect any already open browser.

- For example assume I have Firefox, Google Chrome and Chromium, and I click a link in a PDF file, and Chromium is already open. I want the link to be opened in Chromium.
- At another time, Firefox is open. Then I want the link to be opened in Firefox.

Actually, I want already open browser have more priority than the system default one.

Comment: Normally the browsers detect it themselves and use an existing window unless you use command line parameters like `-no-remote` (Firefox and Chrome AFAIK).

Comment: @phk: no! I don't want a browser detect itself's instance ! i want a scenario like the one i wrote in my edit on Q

Comment: I solved a similar question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515669/195674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Python program uses the [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) module to get a list of processes that belong to you, checks if a known browser is running, and if so, start that one again. If no browser could be found, a default one is started. I've added some comments to clarify what's going on in the script.

Apart from the script itself, you'd still need to make this executable with [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) and make sure that the script is executed instead of launching a particular browser.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import psutil
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import pwd

def getlogin():
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid()).pw_name

def start_browser(exe_path):
    # Popen should start the process in the background
    # We'll also append any command line arguments
    subprocess.Popen(exe_path + sys.argv[1:]) 

def main():
    # Get our own username, to see which processes are relevant
    me = getlogin()

    # Process names from the process list are linked to the executable
    # name needed to start the browser (it's possible that it's not the
    # same). The commands are specified as a list so that we can append
    # command line arguments in the Popen call.
    known_browsers = { 
        "chrome": [ "google-chrome-stable" ],
        "chromium": [ "chromium" ],
        "firefox": [ "firefox" ]
    }

    # If no current browser process is detected, the following command
    # will be executed (again specified as a list)
    default_exe = [ "firefox" ]
    started = False

    # Iterate over all processes
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            info = p.as_dict(attrs = [ "username", "exe" ])
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
        else:
            # If we're the one running the process we can
            # get the name of the executable and compare it to
            # the 'known_browsers' dictionary
            if info["username"] == me and info["exe"]:
                print(info)
                exe_name = os.path.basename(info["exe"])
                if exe_name in known_browsers:
                    start_browser(known_browsers[exe_name])
                    started = True
                    break

    # If we didn't start any browser yet, start a default one
    if not started:
        start_browser(default_exe)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```